# Python selenium presence_of_element_located with only href

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on a link in a forum using Selenium, but I need to wait until the page load, so i thought the better way was to use WebDriverWait. This is my code I used to test it:

```
driver.get("https://testocolo.forumcommunity.net")
#First click, working
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="'+"/?f=9087616"+'"]').click()
    try :
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, '//a[@href="'+"/?t=61904616"+'"]')
        )
        element.click()
    except :
        print("NO")
```

This is the element

```
<a href="/?t=61904616" title="discussione inviata il: 28/10/2020, 19:58">Brotha</a>
```

The try except cycle ends up every time printing "NO".
Before that I tried locating by LINK_TEXT instead, with 'Brotha' but in neither way works. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Increase the time from 2 to 20-30 or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath you can try

```
//a[contains(@tittle,'discussione inviata il')]
```

or

//*[text()='Brotha']

> Next option you can check is if that element is in iframe?

```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Brotha']")))
```

Comment: It is not in iframe, and unfortunatly neither of those options work. If i type driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="'+"/?t=61904616"+'"]') it find the right element and i can click it, but when i use WebDriveWait doesn't.

Comment: use element_to_be_clickable instead of presence_of_element_located and try.

Comment: if its still not working then you need to share more information like URL or relevant details of DOM to further investigate

Comment: I tried everything you suggested but nothing. I update my initial question with more information and the forum link

Comment: //*[text()='Brotha'] xpath is working for me. Kindly check

Comment: I'm doing something wrong for sure because it doesn't work for me. This is what i wrote: EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Brotha']"). Is it correct //*[text()='Brotha'] between " " or should I use ' ' ?

Comment: Missed a (). Now it's working. Thank you very much!